# Executing a Selenium command stored in a variable (Python > Webdriver)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to create a definition that allows me to click on an object regardless of the element type.  To achieve this, I created a variable containing the command I want to run.

```
def clickOnStaleElement(driver, objStrategy, element):
    lhs, rhs = objStrategy.split(".", 1)
    myCommand = "driver.find_element_by_"+rhs.lower()+"(\""+element+"\").click()"
```

I can't seem to figure out how to execute this command that's stored in the variable.  I tried '**driver.execute_script()**' but received a WebDriverException.  Trying '**exec()**', & '**eval()**' resulted in the text hanging.  How do I achieve this?  Is there a better way to go about achieving this behavior?  I realize how I'm trying to achieve this behavior may not be ideal, so I'm open to better ways to accomplish the same task.  I'd prefer not to create 'if/then' statements for each element type, if possible.

Comment: You do not want to do stuff like this. Its bad habit forming and makes the code itself pretty difficult to look at/understand. Plus `exec` or `eval` is almost a curse word around here lol.

Comment: Fair enough, @TehTris.  That's why I asked the second question about a better way of going about achieving this.  I'd prefer to do something other than creating if/then statements for each type of element type possible.  Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary that provides a mapping from a string to a function, then do a simple lookup:

```
strategy = {
    "id":   driver.find_element_by_id,
    "name": driver.find_element_by_name,
    ...
}
find_element = strategy.get(rhs.lower())
find_element(element).click()
```

You probably want to have a default method, or otherwise prepare for the case where `rhs.lower()` doesn't match anything in the dictionary.

Comment: This is slick. This answer deserves to be picked.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan Oakley.  That definitely looks better than what I had.

Answer (score 0):

```
def clickOnStaleElement(driver, objStrategy, element):
    lhs, rhs = objStrategy.split(".",1) #ASSUMING only valid stuff comes down like "???.xpath" , "???.name" "???.id" bla bla ... we'll just keep this here for now....
    if rhs == 'xpath':
        myCommand = driver.find_eleemnt_by_xpath(element) # xpath example, you better hope you entered valid xpath as "element"
    elif rhs == 'id':
        myCommand = driver.find_eleemnt_by_id(element)
    elif rhs == 'name':
       #you get the idea
.
.
.
    else:
        print("rhs, not recognized/valid/watever")
    myCommand.click()
```

I would literally break it down to each having its own If statement on watever `rhs` is.

Also in my opinion, theres no reason to ever pass in "???.somethng" like that into objStrategy, why not just pass in what you actually want?

Comment: Okay, if separating them is my best option, shouldn't I just remove the split command and do this instead?

    `if objStrategy == "By.LINK_TEXT":`
        `driver.find_element_by_link_text(element).click()`
     `elif objStrategy == "By.XPATH":`
        `driver.find_element_by_link_text(element).click()`
     `else:`
        `raise NoSuchElementException("ERROR")`